# How to create wifi direct group with 3 or more devices

Tags: android, wifi-direct

Ive read the android documentation, but it has examples only to connect 2 devices with each other and it works. In last section they mention using createGroup() , but it is for legacy devices and it creates a Soft AP. I need to create a group (one to many) using Wifi Direct only. I want my app to create group of available peers nearby. Something similar to **Samsung Setting app** [image]

If possible please provide the code for creating wifi direct group.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to consider using Google Nearby Connections API instead ([link](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview)). This API uses combination of WIFI and Bluetooth, works without any internet access, has better documentation and it is easier to use.
In your case you should use P2P_STAR strategy.

> P2P_STAR is a peer-to-peer strategy that supports a 1-to-N, or star-shaped, connection topology. In other words, this enables connecting devices within radio range (~100m) in a star shape, where each device can, at any given time, play the role of either a hub (where it can accept incoming connections from N other devices), or a spoke (where it can initiate an outgoing connection to a single hub), but not both.